# Photoshop: Is it possible to create a path from the 'centre point' of a selection, rather than outline?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, selections, pen-tool, outline

I have simple shapes, wirelines from 3ds Max, that I wish to create a path from. In photoshop, if I select the alpha and create a path from selection, the path is created on the outer edges of the wireline as they're 1 pixel wide.

[image]

Is there a way to create a single path that runs **through** these lines so I can have one singular path to work with?

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is in *Photoshop*. But.. perhaps someone else has a trick. Do you have other tools (software)? Tracing a raster image may be an option.

Answer (score 2):

What you seek is commonly called a centerline trace. My research shows me that nothing exists for Adobe Illustrator and there may be an Inkscape extension or feature which works, but I did not pursue that thread.

I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_pfBVePD-g) from a creator who uses Silhouette Studio (craft cutter) presenting a similar requirement. The solution provided in the video is an online resource called [Rapid Resizer](https://online.rapidresizer.com/tracer.php).

It appears that one must begin with a bitmap and select either outline, which you have and do not want, or centerline. It's important to note that centerline trace will not work with T-intersections, but this online resource appears to resolve that by terminating the path short of the intersection. This is apparent in the linked video.

[image: centerline trace screen capture]

Above image is a screen capture from the linked video.

Comment: illustrator has centerline tracing.